# How can i remove double quotes from JSON data in react native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeHBy.png)
I am not able to remove double quotes from json data and store in Async storage

Comment: you don't need to remove the json quotes to store the object in AsyncStorage

Comment: then how will I use that data in homescreen to fetch name ..  and other details

Comment: Try removing the quotations marks around `str = 'responeseJson[0]';` - the right hand side of the assignment is a string with no quotes in it. If you need further assistance, please put the code you're asking about in the question, explain what it is supposed to do and what's going wrong. The post at the moment risks being closed for lack of debugging details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67086014/how-can-i-use-json-data-into-my-screen-in-my-respective-text-fields can you help me with this answer